# Flask on AWS Won't Recognize Controllers

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, flask, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've setup a very small sample of what my app structure looks like on a [python fiddle](https://repl.it/repls/FilthyDarkLicense).

I have a main file to start the application (`application.py`), with controllers in a separate package.

---

The problem I'm facing is, it won't register any routes in `auth.py` (anything in the `controllers` package). It will register any routes in the main script obviously (`application.py`).

I've even checked the logs on AWS Elastic Beanstalk, and the `PYTHONPATH` has the folder in it which contains the `controllers` package.

Locally, this works, but on Elastic Beanstalk it simply won't register those routes.

This is the very small main script (`application.py`):

```
from flask import Flask

application = Flask(__name__)

@application.route('/test/', methods=["GET"])
def test():
    return jsonify({'data': 'This is a test page'})

from controllers import (auth,)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application.debug = True
    application.run()
```

The structure is:

- project

  - controllers

    - **init**.py
    - auth.py
  - application.py

Comment: In my project I import other files with routes by doing (using your paths) `import controllers.auth as auth`. I don't see why this should make a difference, but could be worth a try since it works for me.

Comment: You should also try to do `import project.controllers.auth as auth`